# Azure Data Factory Copy Data SFTP

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to copy data from a .CSV file on an SFTP server to a Azure SQL server using Azure Data Factory.

When configuring the SFTP and mapping the file to the Azure SQL server table, everything is fine and it connects fine (I can preview data from .CSV file on SFTP and auto map columns), but when triggering the pipeline, it fails to connect to the SFTP and I get the following error.

```
Operation on target SFTP failed: ErrorCode=UserErrorNetworkIssue,
'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,
Message=Meet network issue when connect to Sftp server 'sftp.websitename.co.uk', 
SocketErrorCode: 'TimedOut'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,
''Type=System.Net.Sockets.SocketException,
Message=A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond,Source=Renci.SshNet,'
```

Comment: Have you tried to check box for Disable SSH Key Validation and tried?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Comment: Nothing as of yet, still in the dark on it.

Answer (score 0):

Disable SSH Key Validation and tried?

[image]

Comment: It's already disabled. When I click test connection, it says successful. Only when I run the pipeline it fails to connect.